# Call controller Method to return view in javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am working in ASP.Net MVC. I am calling an Action Method from Javascript to redirect to another page. Following is my code.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "JSON",
                url: "@Url.Action("UserExists","Default")",
                data: {Email:$("#Email").val(),Password:$("#Password").val()},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data == "yes") {
                        window.location="Home/Index" + $("#Email").val();// I wnat to send $("#Email).val() to Index method in Home controller.


                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Wrong");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Request and response is fine i.e. ajax calls. But not redirecting to other page, i.e. Home/Index/MyParameter . Please help me how to fix this problem.

Comment: try "/Home/Index" + $("#Email").val();

Answer (score 1):

Try this (i have put in an extra '/' after Index:

```
window.location="Home/Index/" + $("#Email").val();
```

Or this (where email is the name of your action parameter in Index):

```
window.location="Home/Index?email=" + $("#Email").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "/GridOrderSummary/GridRowSummary?ticketId=" + 
ticketId;


 //Controller code
 public class GridOrderSummaryController : Controller
 {

    // GET: GridOrderSummary
    public ActionResult GridRowSummary(string ticketId)
    {
       // your code
        return View();
    }
}
```